# Yarn Workspaces seemingly not recognizing directory

Tags: npm, yarn-workspaces

Wasn't sure the best verbiage for the title, but basically I have a monorepo setup using yarn workspaces. It works for every other directory I have. Here's my layout to make it easy to visualize

```
├── root
├── package.json
├── node_modules
├── appsync
│   ├── package.json
├── aurora
│   ├── package.json
├── lambdas
│   ├── lambda-function-1
│   ├── └── package.json
│   ├── lambda-function-2
│   ├── └── package.json
```

Roughly this is as simple as I can make it without getting into too much unnecessary detail. In my `root` package.json I have my yarn workspaces setup like so:

```
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": [
      "./*",
      "aurora/*",
      "lambdas/**",
    ]
  }
```

The issue is this:

For every other directory I have. Yarn Workspaces is working perfectly. `appsync` is covered in the `./*` declaration. And I have packages in that `package.json` that get installed property to the `root` directory and not in the `appsync` directory. Same with my lambdas. I define those differently because it wont be covered from the `./*` declaration. And this works great too, no issues.

Today I added a new directory, and to my surprise saw modules being installed to `aurora` and not to the root. So I'm very confused whats wrong with my root `package.json` thats causing this? Or any ideas I can try to get more information? I have done `yarn` both at `root` and in the `aurora` directory as well, and no matter what I try, it always installs modules to the `aurora` directory and also adds a `yarn.lock` file to that directory as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Upon looking into this more, it seems like ANY of the packages at the root level without a subdirectory arent working. As soon as I test it by adding 1 sub directory in `aurora` and adding my files there (with package.json). It works! packages are being installed to root and not `aurora` and no `yarn.lock` file in `aurora` either. But why do I need a sub directory? Any insight here is really appreciated.